# how to obtain the list of internal browser css for button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The defaults appearances for a `<button>` in different browser are different.

So i want to put with .animation() [so .toogleClass() does not provide a solution] a color on the button, and after that to go back to the default appearance of the button.

In order to do that, i want to do

```js
var saveOriginalButtonCSS = $("#idbutton").css();
$("#idbutton").css("background-color","#4CAF50");
      
$("#idbutton").animate({
  'background-color': gray
  }, {
    duration : 5000,
    complete : function(){
      $("#idbutton").css(saveOriginalButtonCSS);
  }
});
```

but css() need a parameter.
So how can i do ?
thank's

Comment: May I recommend to have a look here: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: buttons have no default css styling. If the browser renders their appearance differently it must be something other than css. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp